# How block specific page URL in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have deployed web application in IIS. Now I want to block a specific page from specific users.
Is there any way to do this form IIS without using web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna block user for specific page, Then you could use authorization rule with location attribute.

```
<location path="index.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Deny" roles="jokies" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Of course, you can use it for MVC route

```
   <location path="Home/Privacy">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authorization>
                    <add accessType="Deny" users="wicresoft\jokiesd" />
                </authorization>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```